# Moving item with button in jQuery as long as it does not reach a particular position

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, css-position

I have a function that allows users to move an element by clicking a button. However, I only want the button to work as long as the element is not positioned at 100px. This seems to work fine as long as the element's initial position is 100px in which case the button, indeed, has no effect. However, if the item reaches the 100px position after it has already been moved around, the function no longer seems to work, and clicking the button will still move the item even if it is positioned at 100px. Should I be coding this differently?

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() 
    {
        if ( $( ".item" ).css('top') != "100px" ) 
           {
              $( ".item" ).animate({ top: "+=20px" });
           }
});
```

Comment: It works for me. It stops at 100px: http://jsfiddle.net/1vofj82v/

Comment: If you keep clicking the button very fast the div will go out of bounds. The if statement doesn't wait for the animate function to finish. I think that's the problem the OP is facing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `step` option to stop the animation when the limit is reached:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $(".item").animate({
        top: "+=20px"
    }, {
        step: function (top) {
            if (top >= 100) {
                $(".item").stop();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1vofj82v/5/

**EDIT:**
Or if you really want to use the value of `top`:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $(".item").animate({
        top: "+=20px"
    }, {
        step: function (top) {                
            if ($(".item").css("top") == "100px") {
                $(".item").stop();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1vofj82v/6/

**EDIT2:** updated the Fiddle demos to be more demonstrable and changed the code a bit

Comment: If you have any questions about the code, please let me know. I will get back to you as soon as possible.